# Как отлаживать ОС Linux?

Tags: android, linux, отладка

Вы уж извините за столь обобщенный вопрос, но все же. Как отлаживать ОС Linux (в первую очередь, ядро)? Материалов по KGDB, особенно для x86, крайне мало. Да и ещё проблема в том, что многие дистрибутивы используют не ванильное, а пропатченное ядро, а переходить на что-то в духе Arch или Gentoo даже в угоду debug-у я не собираюсь.

И да, хотелось бы ответа для Android: как же на смартфоне отлаживать кастомные ядра? Дело в том, что даже поддержка FBCON есть не для всех ядер. К тому же, по тем или иным причинам, даже она может просто не сработать. А получать dmesg хотя бы по USB по аналогии с ADB очень хочется.

В случае с Android цель даже очевидна: собрать кастомное ядро для фич, недоступных даже на ряде кастомных прошивок (WiFi адаптеры под Kali Linux, Docker-ы, KVM, поддержка ряда файловых систем). Причём на моём телефоне хоть и есть UART, но, во1, он-то используется Bluetooth-адаптером (SoC - Qualcomm SDM660), во2, до него чёрт доберешься. А телефон мне все же жалко, чтобы я его на гвозди разбирал. В QEMU его SoC никак не сэмулировать.

А в случае с ПК история грустная. После смены материнской платы (новая матплата - ASUS Crosshair VI Hero) там начался полнейший хаос. Я пробовал 5 дистрибутивов (включая тот, что уже стоял до смены, Linux Lite). И итог:

- Linux Lite: прямо при загрузке улетал в Kernel Panic
- Devuan 4: криво распознал разрешение экрана, xrandr не спасал
- Trisquel Linux: падал фреймбуфер. Ну т е экран просто замораживался, на нем ничего не происходило.
- Debian 11: Попытался использовать WiFi адаптер: команда `iwconfig wlan0 essid essid_wifi key s:pass` роняла систему намертво (Oops). Хотя на старой плате WiFi работал спокойно, использовал один и тот же драйвер.
- AntiX Linux - аналогично Debian 11, но вместо Oops просто появлялся кошмар в dmesg.
- Gentoo - не смог смонтировать флешку, куда его iso-шник был записан (хотя Gentoo явно умеет работать с Ventoy).
- PureOS - iso-шник не видел экран.

Также грузил Devuan 4 с флешки. Клавиатура, хоть и работала, но жадно писала в dmesg что-то про pcieport, похожее на warning-и.

Есть, конечно, вариант собрать своё ядро из ванильных исходников, но тут две проблемы: все та же отладка + могут быть нужны дистро-специфичные патчи. А так готовый конфиг и даже bzImage у меня давно есть, ибо собираю Linux From Scratch.

Небольшой вопрос: есть ли какие-то "отладочные" дистрибутивы, по аналогии с `eng` и `userdebug` прошивками в Android, чтобы можно было отлаживать ядро и бинарники?

И ещё, какую литературу можете посоветовать для написания драйверов (так сказать, готовлюсь к худшему).

Ещё раз извините за такие вопросы, но такая вот у меня проблема...

Comment: `И ещё, какую литературу можете посоветовать для написания драйверов (так сказать, готовлюсь к худшему).` на хабре свеженький перевод по этой теме был, вот -  [Пособие по программированию модулей ядра Linux](https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/683106/)

Comment: как вы это делаете? в случае ПК диск перекидываешь в новый пк и он запускается...

Comment: Хрен знает, мне поменяли матплату. Просто поменяли матплату. И все полетело, как видите.

Comment: Если "полнейший хаос", то, может, матплата просто бракованная? Винда-то хотя бы работает?

Comment: Windows 11 работает без нареканий

Comment: Стоявшая до windows 11 windows 10 тоже работала без нареканий

Comment: `После смены материнской платы (новая матплата - ASUS Crosshair VI Hero) там начался полнейший хаос` - а bios последний стоит ? ( Версия 8601 2022/08/08 ).

Comment: `Я пробовал 5 дистрибутивов` - негусто, если учесть что Linux Lite и Trisquel основанные на Ubuntu, а Devuan, AntiX и PureOS основанные на Debian.

Comment: Ну, как бы Arch или Alpine особо юзать я не собираюсь. Хотя, Alpine сойдёт в качестве мини-recovery, че бы и нет

Comment: Есть ещё Fedora, NixOS, GuixSD, openSUSE, Android x86

Comment: Версия UEFI - 8601, дату не помню.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Kernel#Troubleshooting

Answer (score 2):

Давненько  я  не страдал,  но  вот  что  могу предложить  из  свежего. "Mastering Linux Device Driver Development: Write custom device drivers to support computer peripherals in Linux operating systems"   но вот это мне боьше  нравиться "Hands-On System Programming With Linux: Explore Linux System Programming Interfaces, Theory, And Practice" https://disk.yandex.ru/i/M2XzUz2OILWVHw   https://disk.yandex.ru/i/PUih1F0hfobnGA