# Как подключиться к wifi при загрузке системы?

Tags: linux, сеть

Смотрите, в чем проблема. Я не могу подключиться к WiFi из командной строки:

```
Linux localhost.localdomain in tty1

Login: rdice779
Password:

rdice779@opensuse_tumbleweed: ~ $ sudo -i
root@opensuse_tumbleweed: ~ # ifconfig wlan0 up
root@opensuse_tumbleweed: ~ # iwconfig wlan0 essid myessid key s:pass
```

Тут орет dmesg:

```
[  143.352114] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[  143.352133] WARNING: CPU: 5 PID: 98 at net/wireless/sme.c:823 __cfg80211_connect_result+0x629/0x640 [cfg80211]
[  143.352194] Modules linked in: nft_fib_inet nft_fib_ipv4 nft_fib_ipv6 nft_fib af_packet nft_reject_inet nf_reject_ipv4 nf_reject_ipv6 nft_reject nft_ct nft_chain_nat nf_tables ebtable_nat ebtable_broute ip6table_nat ip6table_mangle ip6table_raw ip6table_security iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c iptable_mangle iptable_raw iptable_security overlay nfnetlink ebtable_filter ebtables ip6table_filter ip6_tables iptable_filter bpfilter squashfs loop qrtr cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher bnep dmi_sysfs ccm algif_aead af_alg nls_iso8859_1 nls_cp437 vfat fat intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel btusb snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi btrtl snd_hda_codec btbcm btintel edac_mce_amd asus_wmi_sensors btmtk snd_hda_core kvm_amd snd_hwdep eeepc_wmi bluetooth snd_pcm asus_wmi uas kvm battery ledtrig_audio sparse_keymap snd_timer snd platform_profile irqbypass usb_storage joydev
[  143.352231]  video ecdh_generic mxm_wmi wmi_bmof soundcore pcspkr efi_pstore i2c_piix4 k10temp tiny_power_button gpio_amdpt gpio_generic button acpi_cpufreq fuse configfs ip_tables x_tables ext4 mbcache jbd2 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj 8192eu(OE) hid_generic cfg80211 rfkill usbhid amdgpu crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul crc32c_intel polyval_clmulni polyval_generic gf128mul ghash_clmulni_intel xhci_pci xhci_pci_renesas drm_ttm_helper ttm xhci_hcd iommu_v2 gpu_sched aesni_intel drm_buddy crypto_simd cryptd drm_display_helper usbcore cec ccp sp5100_tco rc_core wmi sg dm_multipath dm_mod scsi_dh_rdac scsi_dh_emc scsi_dh_alua msr efivarfs
[  143.352351] Unloaded tainted modules: fjes():1 fjes():1 fjes():1 fjes():1 fjes():1 fjes():1 fjes():1 fjes():1 fjes():1 amd64_edac():1 amd64_edac():1 fjes():1 fjes():1 amd64_edac():1 pcc_cpufreq():1 amd64_edac():1 pcc_cpufreq():1 fjes():1 fjes():1 pcc_cpufreq():1 amd64_edac():1 amd64_edac():1 pcc_cpufreq():1 fjes():1 fjes():1 amd64_edac():1 pcc_cpufreq():1 amd64_edac():1 pcc_cpufreq():1 fjes():1 pcc_cpufreq():1 amd64_edac():1 fjes():1 pcc_cpufreq():1 amd64_edac():1 fjes():1 amd64_edac():1 fjes():1 pcc_cpufreq():1 amd64_edac():1 fjes():1 pcc_cpufreq():1 fjes():1 pcc_cpufreq():1 fjes():1 pcc_cpufreq():1
[  143.352505] CPU: 5 PID: 98 Comm: kworker/u64:11 Tainted: G           OE      6.0.0-1-default #1 openSUSE Tumbleweed e643dffe5da1c767fd409208b04aa78fd6550ddb
[  143.352528] Hardware name: ASUS System Product Name/CROSSHAIR VI HERO, BIOS 8601 07/25/2022
[  143.352545] Workqueue: cfg80211 cfg80211_event_work [cfg80211]
[  143.352585] RIP: 0010:__cfg80211_connect_result+0x629/0x640 [cfg80211]
[  143.352625] Code: 31 ed e9 3e fe ff ff 0f 0b e8 33 07 ee c9 45 31 ed 0f b7 d0 e9 2c fe ff ff 4c 89 e7 e8 50 e2 ff ff 83 3b 00 0f 85 c5 fe ff ff <0f> 0b 48 89 de 4c 89 e7 e8 fa e7 ff ff e9 6a fc ff ff 0f 1f 44 00
[  143.352648] RSP: 0018:ffffc08b0050bdb0 EFLAGS: 00010246
[  143.352659] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffffa0e3051ccc18 RCX: 0000000000000000
[  143.352680] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 00000000fffffe00 RDI: ffffa0e3204e0800
[  143.352692] RBP: ffffc08b0050be10 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[  143.352704] R10: 0000000000000002 R11: ffffa0e63f355000 R12: ffffa0e3204e0800
[  143.352715] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffffa0e3051ccf5a R15: ffffa0e3051ccc18
[  143.352727] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffffa0e63eb40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  143.352739] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[  143.352751] CR2: 000055fe0985ab18 CR3: 0000000126668000 CR4: 00000000003506e0
[  143.352763] Call Trace:
[  143.352772]  <TASK>
[  143.352780]  ? cfg80211_process_wdev_events+0x147/0x1a0 [cfg80211 e377dc58176647de008e3f6c3c5a74df59748eb5]
[  143.352819]  cfg80211_process_wdev_events+0x147/0x1a0 [cfg80211 e377dc58176647de008e3f6c3c5a74df59748eb5]
[  143.353444]  cfg80211_process_rdev_events+0x26/0x40 [cfg80211 e377dc58176647de008e3f6c3c5a74df59748eb5]
[  143.353970]  cfg80211_event_work+0x25/0x30 [cfg80211 e377dc58176647de008e3f6c3c5a74df59748eb5]
[  143.354486]  process_one_work+0x20f/0x3d0
[  143.354978]  worker_thread+0x4a/0x3b0
[  143.355467]  ? process_one_work+0x3d0/0x3d0
[  143.355954]  kthread+0xda/0x100
[  143.356437]  ? kthread_complete_and_exit+0x20/0x20
[  143.356928]  ret_from_fork+0x22/0x30
[  143.357416]  </TASK>
[  143.357896] ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
```

`nmcli dev wifi scan` тоже поорал в dmesg, но wifi точки выдал. А вот подключения через nmcli не работали вообще. Сработал разве что nmtui. Но тут опять вопрос: что работает "под капотом"?

Вот dmesg от nmcli:

```
[ 1128.489219] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[ 1128.489239] WARNING: CPU: 10 PID: 5060 at /var/lib/dkms/rtl8192eu/1.0/build/hal/hal_com.c:11473 SetHwReg+0x46b/0x8f0 [8192eu]
[ 1128.489303] Modules linked in: nft_fib_inet nft_fib_ipv4 nft_fib_ipv6 nft_fib af_packet nft_reject_inet nf_reject_ipv4 nf_reject_ipv6 nft_reject nft_ct nft_chain_nat nf_tables ebtable_nat ebtable_broute ip6table_nat ip6table_mangle ip6table_raw ip6table_security iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c iptable_mangle iptable_raw iptable_security overlay nfnetlink ebtable_filter ebtables ip6table_filter ip6_tables iptable_filter bpfilter squashfs loop qrtr cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher bnep dmi_sysfs ccm algif_aead af_alg nls_iso8859_1 nls_cp437 vfat fat intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel btusb snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi btrtl snd_hda_codec btbcm btintel edac_mce_amd asus_wmi_sensors btmtk snd_hda_core kvm_amd snd_hwdep eeepc_wmi bluetooth snd_pcm asus_wmi uas kvm battery ledtrig_audio sparse_keymap snd_timer snd platform_profile irqbypass usb_storage joydev
[ 1128.489336]  video ecdh_generic mxm_wmi wmi_bmof soundcore pcspkr efi_pstore i2c_piix4 k10temp tiny_power_button gpio_amdpt gpio_generic button acpi_cpufreq fuse configfs ip_tables x_tables ext4 mbcache jbd2 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj 8192eu(OE) hid_generic cfg80211 rfkill usbhid amdgpu crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul crc32c_intel polyval_clmulni polyval_generic gf128mul ghash_clmulni_intel xhci_pci xhci_pci_renesas drm_ttm_helper ttm xhci_hcd iommu_v2 gpu_sched aesni_intel drm_buddy crypto_simd cryptd drm_display_helper usbcore cec ccp sp5100_tco rc_core wmi sg dm_multipath dm_mod scsi_dh_rdac scsi_dh_emc scsi_dh_alua msr efivarfs
[ 1128.489442] Unloaded tainted modules: fjes():1 fjes():1 fjes():1 fjes():1 fjes():1 fjes():1 fjes():1 fjes():1 fjes():1 amd64_edac():1 amd64_edac():1 fjes():1 fjes():1 amd64_edac():1 pcc_cpufreq():1 amd64_edac():1 pcc_cpufreq():1 fjes():1 fjes():1 pcc_cpufreq():1 amd64_edac():1 amd64_edac():1 pcc_cpufreq():1 fjes():1 fjes():1 amd64_edac():1 pcc_cpufreq():1 amd64_edac():1 pcc_cpufreq():1 fjes():1 pcc_cpufreq():1 amd64_edac():1 fjes():1 pcc_cpufreq():1 amd64_edac():1 fjes():1 amd64_edac():1 fjes():1 pcc_cpufreq():1 amd64_edac():1 fjes():1 pcc_cpufreq():1 fjes():1 pcc_cpufreq():1 fjes():1 pcc_cpufreq():1
[ 1128.489575] CPU: 10 PID: 5060 Comm: wpa_supplicant Tainted: G        W  OE      6.0.0-1-default #1 openSUSE Tumbleweed e643dffe5da1c767fd409208b04aa78fd6550ddb
[ 1128.489595] Hardware name: ASUS System Product Name/CROSSHAIR VI HERO, BIOS 8601 07/25/2022
[ 1128.489607] RIP: 0010:SetHwReg+0x46b/0x8f0 [8192eu]
[ 1128.489660] Code: bd 0b 00 00 00 be 04 06 00 00 48 89 df e8 cd 33 f9 ff 84 c0 0f 89 85 fd ff ff bf 01 00 00 00 e8 7b fa 80 c8 40 80 ed 01 75 db <0f> 0b e9 6e fd ff ff 80 3a 01 be a2 06 00 00 0f 84 62 01 00 00 e8
[ 1128.489680] RSP: 0018:ffffc08b011cf4b8 EFLAGS: 00010246
[ 1128.489690] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffffc08b00b35000 RCX: 0000000000000002
[ 1128.489701] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000246 RDI: 0000000000000000
[ 1128.489712] RBP: 0000000000000000 R08: 0000000000000400 R09: 0000000000000001
[ 1128.489722] R10: 0000000000000001 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffffc08b01503000
[ 1128.489733] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffffa0e30286e800
[ 1128.489744] FS:  00007fda609b67c0(0000) GS:ffffa0e63ec80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[ 1128.489755] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[ 1128.489765] CR2: 00007f4ff804c028 CR3: 000000016e528000 CR4: 00000000003506e0
[ 1128.489776] Call Trace:
[ 1128.489784]  <TASK>
[ 1128.489792]  rtw_set_ps_mode+0xb1/0x200 [8192eu 31932af9e65970ff3d64a94d0422a37aa38d86d2]
[ 1128.489843]  LPS_Leave+0xb2/0xc0 [8192eu 31932af9e65970ff3d64a94d0422a37aa38d86d2]
[ 1128.489891]  _rtw_lps_ctrl_wk_cmd+0x42/0x240 [8192eu 31932af9e65970ff3d64a94d0422a37aa38d86d2]
[ 1128.489930]  ? ttwu_queue_wakelist+0xef/0x110
[ 1128.489942]  _rtw_pwr_wakeup+0x25/0x240 [8192eu 31932af9e65970ff3d64a94d0422a37aa38d86d2]
[ 1128.489990]  cfg80211_rtw_scan+0x1ee/0x660 [8192eu 31932af9e65970ff3d64a94d0422a37aa38d86d2]
[ 1128.490046]  ? wake_up_q+0x90/0x90
[ 1128.490694]  ? __wake_up_common+0x73/0x140
[ 1128.491268]  ? update_load_avg+0x7e/0x730
[ 1128.491833]  ? cgroup_rstat_updated+0x42/0xc0
[ 1128.492393]  ? __mod_memcg_state+0x2b/0x80
[ 1128.492953]  ? update_load_avg+0x7e/0x730
[ 1128.493521]  ? newidle_balance+0x2eb/0x420
[ 1128.494086]  ? __update_idle_core+0x20/0xc0
[ 1128.494663]  ? __switch_to_asm+0x3a/0x60
[ 1128.495221]  ? finish_task_switch.isra.0+0x90/0x2d0
[ 1128.495778]  ? __schedule+0x33b/0x12a0
[ 1128.496329]  ? schedule_hrtimeout_range_clock+0xcb/0x120
[ 1128.496879]  ? enqueue_hrtimer+0x2f/0x80
[ 1128.497437]  ? timerqueue_del+0x2a/0x50
[ 1128.497990]  ? __remove_hrtimer+0x39/0x90
[ 1128.498525]  ? select_task_rq_fair+0x15b/0x15f0
[ 1128.499046]  ? packet_poll+0xd3/0x136 [af_packet 35848163dc045f91ee3afa1b093bb07f8124d958]
[ 1128.499577]  rdev_scan+0x28/0xd0 [cfg80211 e377dc58176647de008e3f6c3c5a74df59748eb5]
[ 1128.500135]  nl80211_trigger_scan+0x39a/0x680 [cfg80211 e377dc58176647de008e3f6c3c5a74df59748eb5]
[ 1128.500700]  genl_family_rcv_msg_doit+0xed/0x150
[ 1128.501247]  genl_rcv_msg+0xd8/0x1d0
[ 1128.501788]  ? nl80211_send_scan_start+0xa0/0xa0 [cfg80211 e377dc58176647de008e3f6c3c5a74df59748eb5]
[ 1128.502360]  ? genl_get_cmd+0xe0/0xe0
[ 1128.502900]  netlink_rcv_skb+0x51/0x100
[ 1128.503438]  genl_rcv+0x24/0x40
[ 1128.503973]  netlink_unicast+0x239/0x380
[ 1128.504511]  netlink_sendmsg+0x250/0x4c0
[ 1128.505047]  sock_sendmsg+0x5f/0x70
[ 1128.505588]  ____sys_sendmsg+0x22e/0x270
[ 1128.506125]  ? copy_msghdr_from_user+0x6d/0xa0
[ 1128.506662]  ___sys_sendmsg+0x86/0xd0
[ 1128.507191]  ? __seccomp_filter+0x319/0x4d0
[ 1128.507715]  ? aa_sk_perm+0x3e/0x200
[ 1128.508235]  ? _copy_from_user+0x43/0x60
[ 1128.508742]  ? __seccomp_filter+0x319/0x4d0
[ 1128.509244]  ? aa_sk_perm+0x3e/0x200
[ 1128.509725]  ? _copy_from_user+0x43/0x60
[ 1128.510194]  ? netlink_setsockopt+0x2dc/0x450
[ 1128.510650]  __sys_sendmsg+0x57/0xa0
[ 1128.511089]  do_syscall_64+0x5b/0x80
[ 1128.511513]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x17/0x40
[ 1128.511922]  ? do_syscall_64+0x67/0x80
[ 1128.512317]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x17/0x40
[ 1128.512699]  ? do_syscall_64+0x67/0x80
[ 1128.513068]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x17/0x40
[ 1128.513432]  ? do_syscall_64+0x67/0x80
[ 1128.513784]  ? do_syscall_64+0x67/0x80
[ 1128.514123]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x63/0xcd
[ 1128.514464] RIP: 0033:0x7fda60d1b6c4
[ 1128.514788] Code: ff eb b7 0f 1f 00 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 f3 0f 1e fa 90 90 80 3d dd d2 0d 00 00 74 13 b8 2e 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 54 c3 0f 1f 00 48 83 ec 28 89 54 24 1c 48 89
[ 1128.515125] RSP: 002b:00007ffcaa8a36e8 EFLAGS: 00000202 ORIG_RAX: 000000000000002e
[ 1128.515462] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000561777e362a0 RCX: 00007fda60d1b6c4
[ 1128.515798] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 00007ffcaa8a3720 RDI: 0000000000000006
[ 1128.516137] RBP: 0000561777e56fd0 R08: 0000000000000004 R09: 00007fda60deb320
[ 1128.516477] R10: 00007ffcaa8a3800 R11: 0000000000000202 R12: 0000561777e382d0
[ 1128.516819] R13: 00007ffcaa8a3720 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 00007ffcaa8a3800
[ 1128.517157]  </TASK>
[ 1128.517497] ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
```

`iw` в dmesg ничего не пишет, он просто тихо не работает:

```
root@opensuse_tumbleweed: ~ # iw dev wlan0 connect myessid
```

И да, вообще проблемы не в драйвере на wifi, а в PCI и матплате (о чем я [говорил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1454105/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%9E%D0%A1-linux)), но данный вопрос не об этом, да и какие-то средства подключения к wifi все же работают, пусть и "с пинка". Однако, я хочу автоподключения к WiFi при загрузке (да и графический интерфейс я запускаю руками) Но Opensuse - не Devuan на openrc, там нету `/etc/network/interfaces`...

Что интересно - графическое подключение к wifi (KDE-шное меню, `nmtui`) работают, хоть и "с пинка". Точнее, иногда не с первого раза подключаются, выдавая ошибки (а `dmesg` там уж и молчал...)

*// И это еще и на ядре 6.0.0-1... ппц, ну че там с PCI-то...*

Comment: Я наугад (потому что вы ничего не пишете про методы авторизации на вашей AP) рекомендую почитать маны wpa_supplicant'а

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если работаем с nm то убедись что секрет от вайфая сохранился в /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ и стоит нет autoconnect=false

```
[connection]
autoconnect=true
autoconnect-priority=-999

[wifi-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk=12345678
```